# Windows 7 freezes on HDD access

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, freeze

I have a Windows 7 desktop with a 500Gb SATA hard drive and one 1Tb HDD  (I think both are 5400 rpm) and it's been acting strange for a while.  Two things are very annoying:

1. When I save a file (such as an image) from web browsers, the browser sometimes freezes for a while, sometimes doesn't.  The file doesn't start downloading until the freeze is over.  I suspect a disk access issue since when I download multiple files one after the other, only the first on causes a freeze.
2. When I created a file or a folder from windows explorer, it doesn't show up until I refresh the containing folder.  Same thing when I rename a file or a folder, the change doesn't show up until I refresh.

I notice this behavior on both my disks.  Is this a known issue?  Should I replace my disks with faster ones or is the issue completely unrelated to HDDs?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried another OS? Try loading an Ubuntu LiveCD and tinker with that for a while: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download

Answer (score 2):

You can try a few thing:
First you need to determine what kind of freeze it is:

**Application Hang** - Just the app in question stops responding. `Ctrl-Alt-Del` and all other apps work.
**Soft Freeze** - The whole system hangs up, `Ctrl-Alt-Del` may or may not work. Start menu and all open apps are hung. Mouse Moves on the screen.
**Hard Freeze** - Nothing Works during this operation, mouse is stuck till it responds.

If it is a quick application hang or soft freeze it is most likely an issue accessing that disk. Run a Chkdsk (drive:) -f -r on that drive and your manufacture's drive tools.

If it is a Hard Freeze there may be a problem with your RAM, I would recommend doing a Ram Scan.

With Windows 7 you can see whats going on easily as well to see what resource is being maxed(if any) by pressing `Ctrl-Shift-Esc`, then from task manager go to the Performance Tab, then click on resource manager.

Finally, you may want to use the system file checker(SFC) by running SFC /scannow

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's an application hang as everything else works.  I'll run a chkdsk and SFC and investigate a little more tonight when I get home and come back here with feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest chipset drivers for my motherboard and installed them.  After a system restart, the problem went away.

In case of weird problems with the hard drive, I suggest you try this first as it won't hurt anything to update the drivers and may save you a great deal of time.

Comment: So your suggestion is to update drivers and reboot? The answer is very full with text and the point is hard to get. I suggest an edit.